# Grouping elements by date

Tags: php, arrays, odbc, grouping

I have a code below:

```
 for($j=0; $j<=odbc_fetch_row($result); $j++){  
            
                  
                   $date = odbc_result($result, 'DATE');
                    $A = odbc_result($result, 'A');
                   $B = odbc_result($result, 'B');
                   $C = odbc_result($result, 'C');
                   $D = odbc_result($result, 'D');
                   $E= odbc_result($result, 'E');
                   
                   echo $date." ".$A." ".$B." ".$C." ".$D." ".$E."<br/>";
}
```

> ```
> DATE  A  B  C  D  E
> 20140101 0 8225.12 0 0 0
> 20140101 18483.28 0 0 0 0
> 20140101 0 0 12275.49 0 0
> 20140101 0 0 0 3013.50 0
> 20140101 0 0 0 0 4552.20
> 20140102 0 3612.30 0 0 0
> 20140102 6850.10 0 0 0 0
> 20140102 0 0 5695.45 0 0
> 20140102 0 0 0 3291.80 0
> 20140102 0 0 0 0 2006.20
> 20140103 0 2684.10 0 0 0
> 20140103 13342.26 0 0 0 0
> 20140103 0 0 6981.14 0 0
> 20140103 0 0 0 3887.93 0
> 20140103 0 0 0 0 5117.50
> ```

How do I group the elements by the date like the following?

> DATE  A  B  C  D  E
>
> 20140101 18483.28 8225.12 12275.49 3013.50 4552.20
> 20140102 6850.10 3612.30 5695.45 3291.80 2006.20

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$result = array();
 for($j=0; $j<=odbc_fetch_row($result); $j++){
      $date = odbc_result($result, 'DATE');
      $A = odbc_result($result, 'A');
      $B = odbc_result($result, 'B');
      $C = odbc_result($result, 'C');
      $D = odbc_result($result, 'D');
      $E= odbc_result($result, 'E');
      $row = array($date,$A,$B,$C,$D,$E);
      for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++){
         if($row[$i]>0) {
             $result[$date][$i] = $row[$i];
         }
      }  
 }
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/98925)

Comment: THanks. However, how do I print out the values not in array format?

Comment: How do you want to print? you can use implode

Comment: For that you can just loop the result array

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in mysql query directly as below assuming your data pattern is same meaning for each row any one of the columns in a,b,c,d,e will have a value and rest all 0 as

```
SELECT `date`,
       max(`a`) as `a`,
       max(`b`) as `b`,
       max(`c`) as `c`,
       max(`d`) as `d`,
       max(`e`) as `e` 
 FROM `test`
GROUP BY `date`
```

So after executing the query you get the data by loop

check here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4952f0/12